# I can't load a JSON result file from a SPARQL endpoint

Tags: angularjs, sparql

I'm writting a AngularJS controller that loads data from a SPARQL endpoint using the next code:

```javascript
var namedgraphApp = angular.module('namedgraphApp', []);

namedgraphApp.controller('NamedgraphListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('http://some-sparql-endpoint/query', {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            query: "SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 10",
            output: 'json'
        },
        headers: { Authorization: auth }
    }).success(function(res){
        console.log(res.data);
        $scope.namedgraphs = res.data;
    });
});
```

When using the Chromium browser It recives the downloaded data that is a json file, but shows up the next error message in the browser console:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/sparql-results+json: "http://some-sparql-endpoint/...". angular.min.js:70
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The no data is rendered in the template. So I think that the problem could be that the SPARQL endpoints sents the data using `application/sparql-results+json` instead of `application/json`, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The first message is probably a warning displayed by Chrome. The second errors has something to do with the jsonp request. Is the request correct and is returning valid data?

Comment: Yes, it returns a valid JSON file.

Comment: Does it return a valid `JSONP` file? Did you mean to use `output: 'jsonp'` in the code?

Comment: I try adding that option to parameters for the `$http` function, but it don't works. Also I don't see the `output` option in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http).

Comment: Try putting callback : YourFunction in the params to get JSONP.

Comment: I got the same error.